# Unpack nested JSON in Next.js

Tags: javascript, json, next.js

I am attempting to unpack nested JSON via a fetch function I created. But, I am unsure how to get a specific array, for example pull the 'date' from index of 1. Currently, this is what I have:

```
Home.getInitialProps = async function() {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.covidtracking.com/v1/us/daily.json')
  const data = await res.json()
  return {
   //Obviously this is providing me with an error
    data[1].date 

  }
}
```

My JSON:

```
[{"date":20210112}, {"date":20210111}, {"date":202101131}]
```

What is the correct way to do this, and subsequently get the values inside of the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
return { 
  date: data[0]['date']
}
```

> If you're using Next.js 9.3 or newer, we recommend that you use
> `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` instead of getInitialProps.
> https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps

Comment: Worked great -- just had to change the return to return { props: { ... because of GetStaticProps. Thank you!